# tailing file in new terminal window

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, iterm

I have the following two bash scripts (perhaps they can be condensed into one).

// pre-tail.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
open -b com.apple.terminal `dirname $0`/tail.sh
```

// tail.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tail -F ${FILE_TO_TAIL}
```

I would execute like so:

```
FILE_TO_TAIL=some.log ./pre-tail.sh
```

so I launch the first one, and ideally the output of the second bash script would appear in a new terminal window, but it doesn't quite work. Anyone have an idea why?

My other question is - instead of using com.apple.terminal, is there a more agnostic way to open up a new terminal window and run a command?

Comment: Have you tried using `tee` or `tee -a`?  (See `man tee`.)

Comment: Define “doesn't quite work”. What's wrong? In what way does it partly work, but not completely?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, but it's clearly not tailing a file, my guess is that it's not picking up ${FILE_TO_TAIL}, because when I hard code the correct path to a log file on that line, it works, any idea why that wouldn't reference the right value? I am using absolute paths in either case, so it shouldn't be a (relative) path issue.